# Is Luke 22:53 a reference to Satan?

Tags: luke, sin, satan, demons, crucifixion

I was reading a book on “Satan & His Deception” by various authors (small booklet).  In it, A.W. Pink referenced Luke 22:53 to Satan/devil, but I am not sure it is a reference to Satan.

> Then Jesus said to the chief priests, captains of the temple, and the
> elders who had come to Him, “Have you come out, as against a  robber,
> with swords and clubs? When I was with you daily in the  temple, you
> did not try to seize Me. **But this is your  hour, and the power of
> darkness**.” Luke 22:52-53

Another way to interpret it might be in reference to their sin?

**Q: How do we interpret this verse?**

To quote A.W. Pink:

> “Satan is “the power of darkness” (Luk 22:53), and only the light of
> God can expose and expel him.” Pg.34

Answer (score 1):

A W Pink agrees with Bengel who writes of Luke 22:53 -

> **“The prince of this world”**: of darkness, that is to say, of Satan. The abstract put for the concrete.

We may recall parallel texts such as:

- Col 1:13 - He has rescued us from the **dominion of darkness** and brought us into the kingdom of His beloved Son
- Acts 26:18 - to open their eyes, so that they may turn from **darkness to light** and **from the power of Satan to God**, that they may receive forgiveness of sins and an inheritance among those sanctified by faith in Me.’
- John 12:31 - Now judgment is upon this world; now the **prince of this world** will be cast out.
- John 14:30 - I will not speak with you much longer, for the **prince of this world** is coming, and he has no claim on Me.
- John 16:11 - and in regard to judgment, because the **prince of this world** has been condemned.
- Eph 6:12 - For our struggle is not against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against **the powers of this world’s darkness**, and against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms.
- 1 Cor 2:6 - Among the mature, however, we speak a message of wisdom—but not the wisdom of this age or of the **rulers of this age**, who are coming to nothing.
- 1 Cor 2:8 - None of the **rulers of this age** understood it. For if they had, they would not have crucified the Lord of glory.
- Matt 6:23 - But if your eyes are bad, your whole body will be **full of darkness**. If then the light within you is darkness, how great is that darkness!

Note the text of Luke 22:53 -

> Every day I was with you in the temple courts, and you did not lay a
> hand on Me. But this hour belongs to you and to the **power of
> darkness**.”

This phrase "power of darkness" has been understood in several ways such as:

1. Satan specifically which might be strengthened by the opposite where Jesus claims to be the "light of the world" (John 8:12).  See also Acts 26:18, Col 1:13
2. the combined evil rulership of the world - note the plural in many of the texts above, eg, Eph 6:12, 1 Cor 2:6, 8
3. the general power of human sinfulness and its collective sinful nature, eg, Matt 6:23
4. The general influence (on humans and human existence) of Satan and his minions who control the kingdom of darkness, eg, Col 1:13,

In fact, a slightly different case could be made in each of the above texts.  In the specific case of Luke 22:53, commentators are divided between option #1 above and option #4 (and few in #3).  My personal preference is option #4 above; however, since Satan rules the kingdom of darkness, the leader is often used as name of the kingdom.

Comment: Interesting survey, +1.